# Django object has no attribute

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a bulk Update. Each message created I need to call .send(gateway)  This is what I have tried:

```
  objs = [                               
        Message(                           
            recipient_number=e.mobile,     
            content=content,               
            sender=e.contact_owner,        
            billee=user,                   
            sender_name=sender             
        ).send(gateway)                                  
        for e in query                     

    ]                                      
    # Send messages to DB                  
    Message.objects.bulk_create(objs)
```

I get this error:

**Task Request to Process with id 3ab72d3c-5fd8-4b7d-8cc5-e0400455334f raised exception:
'AttributeError("\'NoneType\' object has no attribute \'pk\'",)'**

why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating the `objs` list by calling `send` on each element of `query`. Presumably, `send` does not return anything and you get a list of `None`. Try this:

```
objs = []
for element in query:
    message = Message(**kwargs)
    message.send(gateway)
    objs.append(message)

Message.objects.bulk_create(objs)
```

`**kwargs` is just a placeholder for all the parameters you pass to Message. You can use a dictionary or just pass all the parameters as in your original code.

As a side note, list comprehensions are usually indicated when you want a new list and not for side effects (like sending a message). Here you want both, so the `for` loop is appropriate.

Comment: I think send can only be called when saved to the DB, as its not saved until bulk is done are you sure this is not the issue?

Comment: If that is the case, your original `send` would also fail (my suggestion doesn't change anything in that regard). But then you should do the list comprehension without `.send(gateway)` and do a `for` loop on the `objs` Message objects after calling `bulk_create`, to `send` each of them.